# Grabbing Elements from Another Website using jQuery

Tags: jquery

**WebPage1.html** -> *Contains my actual content*

**WebPage2.html** -> *Contains some elements I want to show on WebPage1.html*

So according to the info above, how to grab elements from another page/domain/etc. show them on my page with jQuery?

I don't want to load entire page, just lets say only headers or a dropdown list or something else but only some parts.

I hope I express my questions exactly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If WebPage2 lives in another domain, you can't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do is a jquery ajax request. [This page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) describes that API. You would then use jquery selectors to extract only the elements you wanted then modify your DOM in such a way as to display them.

While in most cases, @spender is correct about cross domain requests, [this link](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html) might help.

This shows how you can perform an ajax call to your own server and have it grab (and hopefully santize/process) the response you want.

This is often thought of as a poor practice and if you state what problem you are looking to solve we may be able to give you better advice.

Comment: Can you please refine/specify your answer? I'm quite the beginner at **jQuery** and tend to get very lost in the API. Let's make it easy, say **WebPage2.html** has a `#some-heading` that you want to appear in **WebPage1.html**.

Comment: jQuery has manuals on how to select individual elements. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Load the page body you want, select just the element you want using the selector tutorial, and then refresh the elements of the page you want to show it. See the examples at the bottom of the ajax request api for details on that part.

Answer (score 1):

If WebPage2 lives in another domain, you can't do this.

If they are on the same domain, then you can create an `iframe` (possibly hidden), load the document there, examine it and copy the part that you want. [This should get you started](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/).

HTML has no way to partially load HTML documents. You either get everything or nothing.